# How to filter grouped by in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie in Pandas. I have the following dataset.
Think of the dataset as departments('k1') and people('k2') of a company.

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame({'k1': ['X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z'],
   ...:                         'k2': ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6'],
   ...:                          'dataset1': np.random.randn(6)})
   ...:
```

If I take the mean grouped by dept/'k1' I get the following

```
   dataset1
k1
X   0.153825
Y  -0.648500
Z   1.133334
```

If I take the mean grouped by people/'k2', I get the following

```
In [6]: dframe.groupby('k2').mean()
Out[6]:
    dataset1
k2
P1  1.595455
P2 -1.287805
P3  0.211858
P4 -1.508859
P5  1.350336
P6  0.916332
```

My question is how can I filter only the mean values grouped by people/'k2' which is greater than the mean of dept/'k1' to which it belongs. e.g. P1 mean value is greater than X mean value to which it belongs

```
Out[6]:
    dataset1
k2
P1  1.595455
P3  0.211858
P5  1.350336
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael . I understood what transformation does.Beautiful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample (changed `P6` to `P5`):

```
np.random.seed(45)
dframe = pd.DataFrame({'k1': ['X','X','Y','Y','Z','Z'],
                         'k2': ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P5'],
                            'dataset1': np.random.randn(6)})

print (dframe)
   dataset1 k1  k2
0  0.026375  X  P1
1  0.260322  X  P2
2 -0.395146  Y  P3
3 -0.204301  Y  P4
4 -1.271633  Z  P5
5 -2.596879  Z  P5
```

First create new column by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
dframe['meank1'] = dframe.groupby('k1').transform('mean')
print (dframe)
   dataset1 k1  k2    meank1
0  0.026375  X  P1  0.143348
1  0.260322  X  P2  0.143348
2 -0.395146  Y  P3 -0.299723
3 -0.204301  Y  P4 -0.299723
4 -1.271633  Z  P5 -1.934256
5 -2.596879  Z  P5 -1.934256
```

Then aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) `mean` and [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), also is necessary add `k1` column to `groupby` for avoid wrong output if same `k2` in another `k1`.

```
dframe = dframe.groupby(['k1','k2']).agg({'dataset1':'mean', 'meank1':'first'})
print (dframe)
         meank1  dataset1
k1 k2                    
X  P1  0.143348  0.026375
   P2  0.143348  0.260322
Y  P3 -0.299723 -0.395146
   P4 -0.299723 -0.204301
Z  P5 -1.934256 -1.934256
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
dframe = dframe.loc[dframe['meank1'] > dframe['dataset1'], ['dataset1']]
#alternative sol
#dframe = dframe.query('meank1 > dataset1')[['dataset1']]
print (dframe)
       dataset1
k1 k2          
X  P1  0.026375
Y  P3 -0.395146
```

And if want remove first level of `MultiIndex` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
dframe = dframe.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (dframe)
    dataset1
k2          
P1  0.026375
P3 -0.395146
```

For column from index use:

```
dframe = dframe.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
print (dframe)
   k2  dataset1
0  P1  0.026375
1  P3 -0.395146
```